# opera browser displays margin differently

Tags: css, layout, margin, opera

I'm going nuts on this, I can't figure out what causes the margins of the right sidebar gallery images to be rendered differently on opera browser. More specifically the bottom margin of the images seems to be doubled in every other common browser, its set to 2px and only opera displays it as 2 px.

This is the url - http://www.roxopolis.de/media See screenshots [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYkAa.jpg).

Please help me out with this, I don't care too much about the fact that its displayed differently but it exposes a bit of the following gallery images which are supposed to remain hidden so thats what bothers me. If there is another way to hide the following images (which are placed by widget) that'd be fine too. Maybe setting the margin conditionally for opera?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a quick look at the page in Dragonfly as well as Chrome's inspector for comparison and no particular style, including inherited ones, strikes me as "causing" this issue. Maybe someone else can find something, but at a glance, I'd say Opera seems to be "doing the right thing".

You might have more control over the spacing if you put each anchor tag along with its respective image inside its own container and tried to style those (e.g. a div containing the anchor containing the image for each item, and float them left within the parent container div).

Is there a particular reason you have more images than you want to display? I don't see any controls to scroll the images on that page, so I'm not sure why you need to have more than the six images you're showing already. Surely if you have code somewhere that randomises the order, you can change it so that it only displays the first six images.

Also, have you tried breaking the problem down to a smaller use case that can be tested/tweaked in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? That may help to get to the bottom of your issue if you can't solve it using the above suggestion.

Comment: Alright thank's for your answer, first of all.

The thing that makes this a bit more complicated is that the code is generated by a plugin (NextGen Widget). So I can't just break it down or code it manually with the styles this plugin provides because the plugin allows easy integration of future images for the gallery.

Comment: The reason I want more images to be displayed than people can see is that this allows people to browse through the entire gallery while only exposing 6 images. It's kind of a pity that the plugin doesn't have this option but that's what I wanted to achieve by hiding the rest.
To scroll the images you click one of them and it pops up the image browser by the way, maybe I need to make it more obvious because you said you found no way to scroll them.